# Export Plot as EPS File for Import into Illustrator with Bezier Curves

Tags: eps-format

Is it possible to export a Plot graphic as an `.EPS` which can be opened by Illustrator and edited as bezier curves with the pen tool?

At the moment, the `.EPS` file I open with Illustrator contains lots of closely spaced points creating the curve but with no bezier curve I can edit with the pen tool.

Comment: `Plot[]` produces a polyline and not a Bézier curve. You'll have to do more work if you absolutely must have a Bézier.

Comment: If you find an answer to your question please provide also solution for this one http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110420/how-to-export-a-3d-circle-as-a-single-piece-pdf-vectorial-object/110436#110436

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ifnToBezierCurve[]` from [Convert interpolating function to a Bezier curve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270575/convert-interpolating-function-to-a-bezier-curve), which I converted to a package.

#### Proof of concept

The following shows a very minimal example. I limited the number of points plotted. I also used `Show[]` to remove the axes so that the `ExportString[]` would not have compressed data.

```
Get@"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mroge02/ifnToBezierCurve/main/ifnToBezierCurve.wl"

plot = Plot[x^3 - 2 x^2, {x, 0, 2}, PlotPoints -> 4, 
   MaxRecursion -> 0];
bezierPlot = Normal@Show[plot, Axes -> None] /. 
   Line[p_] :> ifnToBezierCurve@Interpolation[p];

ExportString[bezierPlot, "EPS"]
```

> ```
> %!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0  
> ...  
> %%BeginProlog
> ...
> /c { curveto } bind def
> ...
> %%EndProlog
> ...
> 0.368414 0.506783 0.709804 rg
> 1.44 w
> 2 J
> 0 j
> [] 0.0 d
> 3.25 M 5.184 8.008 m 31.777 8.012 58.367 41.352 84.961 75.969 c 113.789 113.5 
> 142.617 152.523 171.445 152.184 c 198.969 151.859 226.492 115.656 254.016
>  8.012 c S
> Q Q
> showpage
> %%Trailer
> end
> %%EOF
> ```

Visualization.
The following shows the original plot and a comparison of the Bezier curve plot the regular plot of the function. Because the number of points is very small, the `Plot[]` polyline does not reflect the curvature of the graph, whereas the cubic Bezier curve draws the graph of the cubic exactly.

```
GraphicsRow[{plot /. 
   Line[p_] :> {Line[p], Directive[Magenta, PointSize@Large], 
     Point[temp = p]},
  Show[
   Plot[x^3 - 2 x^2, {x, 0, 2}, 
    PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[6], Black}],
   Plot[x^3 - 2 x^2, {x, 0, 2}, 
    PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[5], LightYellow}],
   bezierPlot, 
   Graphics[{Directive[Magenta, PointSize@Large], Point[temp]}], 
   Axes -> True]
  }]
```

[image]

#### A more robust replacement rule

Another example with a normal plot, which also shows how to process a line in a `GraphicsComplex`.

```
lineToBezier = {
   GraphicsComplex[pts_, g_, opts___] :> 
    GraphicsComplex[pts, 
     g /. {Line[p_?(VectorQ[#, IntegerQ] &)] :> 
        ifnToBezierCurve@Interpolation[pts[[p]]]}, opts],
   Line[p_?(MatrixQ[#, Developer`RealQ] &)] :> 
    ifnToBezierCurve@Interpolation[p]
   };

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> 15, 
  MeshStyle -> Red] /. lineToBezier
```

Note that converting to Bezier curves would destroy any gradient coloring of the curve. (`Line` supports `VertexColors`, but `BezierCurve` does not in 2D.)

#### Using `NDSolve` to avoid oversampling

`Plot` generates a lot of points. If you want fewer points, using `NDSolve` is perhaps a more efficient approach.

```
plot2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}];

{ifn1} = Cases[
   plot2,
   Line[p_] :> Interpolation[p],
   Infinity];

ifn2 = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == D[Sin[x], x], y[0] == Sin[0]}, 
   y, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   (* pick order/precision appropriate for a plot *)
   Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 3}, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 3];

Comap[{ifn1, ifn2}, "Grid"] // Map@Length

(* {431, 30} -- NDSolve has a lot fewer points *)
```

Visualization:

```
Labeled[
 Show[
  Graphics[{
    Black,
    AbsoluteThickness[6],
    ifnToBezierCurve[ifn1],
    Yellow,
    AbsoluteThickness[5],
    ifnToBezierCurve[ifn2]
    }, Options@Plot],
  plot2
  ],
 Grid[{{Graphics[{#[[1]] &[
       "DefaultPlotStyle" /. (Method /. 
          Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, Plot])], 
      AbsoluteThickness[2], Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 1.1}, {-0.1, 0.1}}, ImageSize -> {40, 16}], 
    HoldForm[Sin[x]]},
   {Graphics[{
      Yellow,
      AbsoluteThickness[5],
      Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 1.1}, {-0.1, 0.1}}, ImageSize -> {40, 16}]
    , "Plot Bezier"},
   {Graphics[{Black,
      AbsoluteThickness[6],
      Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}],
      White,
      AbsoluteThickness[5],
      Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 1.1}, {-0.1, 0.1}}, ImageSize -> {40, 16}]
    , "NDSolve Bezier"}}],
 Right
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have better luck with just copying the graphic from Mathematica 13.2 (I use SciDraw package for plots) and pasting into Illustrator (version 27.4.1). In this manner, I can also change fonts.