# Projecting Graphics3D onto the 2D plane for vector export (and solving other issues; revisited)

Tags: graphics, export, graphics3d, rendering

**tl;dr:**

**Q:** How can we turn a `Graphics3D` into a manageable `Graphics` object with only 2D graphics primitives for vector export?

**A:** I have came up with a partial solution which has room for improvement; scroll down to see it in a self-answer. To see remaining questions, head down to the bottom of this post.

---

There have been several questions on this subject, concerning rendering 3D graphics into vector, projecting 3D graphics onto a 2D plane, z-buffering and/or z-sorting, exporting 3D scenes, etc. etc. Here's just a small sample of such questions:

- [How to export a 3D circle as a single piece PDF vectorial object?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110420/26956)
- [How to turn off depth sorting of 3D curves for Manipulate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109742/26956)

The above two questions stand out a bit. Exporting `Graphics3D[Line[{p1,p2,p3,...}]]` in vector renders rather more like `line(p1,p2), line(p2,p3), line(p3, p4)...` which is related to [z-buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering), an effect that OP there direly wanted to disable.

- [Converting 3D graphics to 2D for better export](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139050/26956)
- [Exporting 2D & 3D graphics for use in Adobe Illustrator](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92133/26956)
- [Export Plot3D in Mathematica 10.1 is Rasterized by default](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87733/26956)
- [How can I export 3D plots as vector graphics?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100156/26956)

There are many others which I may have missed. In particular, there is a [beautiful QA](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45410/26956) which creates schematic drawings of 3D objects with hidden lines dashed, though it rasterizes the image.

Thus, lately, I have been wondering to myself, if we could somehow replicate the rendering engine of MMA and convert a `Graphics3D` directly into `Graphics` and 2D primitives.

---

Footnote:

The typical way a `Graphics3D` can be exported as vector is something like

```
Graphics[{}, Epilog -> Inset[Graphics3D[...]]]
```

If something complicated and/or high-poly is presented there, the resulting pdf file is huge.

---

As I have a partial solution, I have follow-up questions (this is just an incomplete subset of possible improvements):

- Can we do better than my solution (improve or rewrite completely?)
- `Sphere[{x,y,z}, r]` cannot be rendered in `Graphics`, but a straightforward conversion is `/. Sphere -> Disk`. What else can be done to generalize things? What can be done better?
- As an example, a uniformly-colored convex polyhedron with `FaceForm[Opacity[.2]]` rendered in `Graphics3D` will still look like it has volume. The same polyhedron, passed through my processor will look like a flat polygon with `Opacity[.4]`. Maybe we could adjust the colors of surfaces (polygons) depending on their normals and the view direction?

Answer (score 3):

I came up with the following solution:

```
wrapper[g_Graphics3D, vp_, vv_: {0., 0., 1.}, vc_: Automatic] :=
 Module[{pr = Tuples[PlotRange[g]],
   pts = Union@Cases[g, {Repeated[_Real, {3}]}, Infinity],
   newpts, vVert, vCent, vDepth, transform, rot, rot2D, rules},
  rules = Thread[pts -> Range[Length@pts]];
  If[vc === Automatic, vCent = RegionCentroid@ConvexHullMesh@pts, 
   vCent = vc];
  vDepth = vp - vCent; newpts = pts\[Transpose] - vCent // Transpose;
  pr = pr\[Transpose] - vCent // Transpose;
  rot = RotationTransform[{vDepth, {0, -1, 0}}];
  vDepth = rot[vDepth][[2]];
  newpts = rot[newpts];
  vVert = rot[vv];
  rot2D = RotationTransform[{vVert[[{1, 3}]], {0, 1}}];
  transform = 
   Compile[{x, y, z}, {(vDepth x)/(vDepth - y), (vDepth z)/(vDepth - y)},
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
  pr = Map[Norm, (transform @@ Transpose[rot[pr]])] // Max;
  newpts = transform @@ Transpose[newpts];
  newpts = rot2D[newpts];
  Graphics[{GraphicsComplex[newpts, First@g /. rules]}, 
   Join[{PlotRange -> {{-pr, pr}, {-pr, pr}}}, List @@ Rest[g]]]
  ]
```

Here it is in action. The original image is given by

```
im = Uncompress[Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/QHVeNCty", "String"]]
```

[image]

While the 2D projection can be obtained and manipulated by

```
Manipulate[
 wrapper[im /. {Sphere -> Disk, Tube -> (Identity[#] &), 
      h_[None] :> h[Opacity[0]]} /. FaceForm -> Identity // 
   DeleteCases[#, (PlotLabel -> _), Infinity] &, {-20, y, z}, {0, 1, 
   0}], {y, 0, 20}, {z, 0, 30}]
```

[image]

The way my wrapper works, is by taking a viewpoint `vp` (closely analogous to `ViewPoint` of `Graphics3D`, but unscaled coordinates), taking a view vertical, optionally a view center (`vc`, i.e. the point at which the camera is directed). Then it finding all points in the `Graphics3D`:

```
pts = Union@Cases[g, {Repeated[_Real, {3}]}, Infinity]
```

rotates and translates the scene, so that we project onto the xz plane and does a pinhole camera projection. A pdf export of the result is only 19KB. I'm not even trying to export the original `Graphics3D` to vector, but it's in the ballpark of 5MB at least.

Comment: This is very nice!