# Export Graphics3D in Vectorial Form

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, export

I am trying to export a `Graphic3D` object in a vectorial form in PDF. However, the previous methods suggested in [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172894/projecting-graphics3d-onto-the-2d-plane-for-vector-export-and-solving-other-iss?rq=1) do not work for version 12.3 now. Both `Export[NotebookDirectory[]<>"foo.pdf",Graphics[Inset[Graphics3D[Sphere[]]]]]` and trying to print the graphics via Microsoft-Print-to PDF produces a fuzzy rasterized pdf file, which is undesired. So what is the correct way to export such graphics?

**UPDATE**
I supposed that something like `Graphics3D[Raster3D[{{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}}/10]]` should be more easily exported, but I still have no idea on how to operate on it.

Comment: Does the solution here help?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/172894/1871